# Update across schemas in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to update a table with data from another schema. Why does this not work?

```
UPDATE table a
SET a.value = b.value
FROM other_schema.table b
WHERE a.id = b.id AND b.value IS NOT NULL;
```

I've tried this with a join on id as well, but with the same syntax error.

Comment: It always help to say *what* error you get.

Comment: "Syntax error" is the error.

Comment: Then you need a new client/IDE, as something is hiding the actual error from you, in a very unhelpful way. I think that would get an ORA-00932 off the top of my head.

Comment: I agree the IDE was not very helpful in this instance. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support a `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` statement.  You'd want something like

```
UPDATE table a
   SET a.value = (SELECT b.value
                    FROM other_schema.table b
                   WHERE a.id = b.id 
                     AND b.value IS NOT NULL)
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT b.value
                FROM other_schema.table b
               WHERE a.id = b.id 
                 AND b.value IS NOT NULL)
```

You could omit the `EXISTS` if you want to update every row in `a` whether or not there is a match in `b` but I assume that is not your goal.

If your join produces a key-preserved result, you could also

```
UPDATE( SELECT a.id, a.value a_value, b.value b_value
          FROM table a
               JOIN other_schema.table b
                 ON a.id = b.id AND
                    b.value IS NOT NULL )
   SET a_value = b_value;
```